# "Duplicate Entry Error" 1062 on Replicated SQL Databases

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave

When trying to replicate a database between a master and a slave on VM box, I have received the above errors. This is a telephony solution and the error output relates to a call made on the system. I have repeated the setup process a number of times, however have received the 1062 error everytime I start the slave - although the error output does not remain the same.

I decided to spin up a new VM machine with all the same specifications, in order to prove it wasnt a machine-specific issue, but received the same error code, but with different details in the error output.

I have read answers that show that auto-increment could be the issue, but if I use auto_increment, will this resolve this?

Thanks in advance, Ian

Comment: 1062 is a Duplicate key error. Run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` on the slave to find the error so you can fix that. And then you can decide whether auto_increment will help you going forward.

Comment: @IGGt  -  I have already run the SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G Command to find one error, however, this does also throw up an IO error 1595 - "Relay Log Write failure - could not write queue event from master" - This may relate to a part of the SQL database which is processing information from the programming on the telephony platform (call-centre queues)

Comment: That sounds to me like a corrupt bin-log on the master. Do you have other slave DB's running OK? Have a look at http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62368/how-do-i-fix-replication-event-checksum-verification-failed-while-reading-from-n for a fix for this.